# How to determine the parameter in a differential equation with some fixed solution

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear

Assuming that I have a ODE system with undetermined parameter 
$$x''(t) == y(t) x(t)$$
$$y'(t) == 2 - a x(t)$$

and I have some fixed solution condition
$$x(0)=0$$
$$x(10)=8$$
$$y(10)=3.5$$

Is there a way to determine the parameter `a`,
I tried to solve this ODEs with both `NDSolve` and `DSolve`, but it seems not to work.

```
 NDSolve[{x''[t] == y[t] x[t], y'[t] == 2 - a x[t], x[0] == 0, 
  x[10] == 8, y[10] == 3.5}, {x, y}, t]
```

the output is

> NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 0.`.

can somebody help me? Thank you very much.

Comment: In order to determine `a` you need one more condition. Three conditions are required to solve the differential equations for a particular parameter, since you've got (effectively) a third-order ordinary differential equation.

Comment: Hi, @march thank you very much, I have tried to add another condition, such as $y(0)=2.5$. However, the same problem still exist.

Comment: @ZihuGuo Do u have any conditions on the parameter "a"?

Comment: @thils `a` is a real number

Answer (score 2):

As a first step:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] == y[t] x[t], y'[t] == 2 - a x[t], 
   x[0] == 0, x[10] == 8, y[10] == 3.5}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
```

For example a = 1, you can plot

```
 {Plot[x[a][t] /. a -> 1 /. sol, {t, 0, 10}], 
 Plot[y[a][t] /. a -> 1 /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]}
```

[image]

To determine a, the following plots can help:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[a][t] /. sol, {a, -1, 1}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[x[a][t] /. sol, {a, -1, 1}]], {t, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

If you are playing with the value a then verify the bcs and ics!
You never get y[0]==2.5

Comment: ， Thank you very much, it is fantastic. But I am afraid it is not a general method. In this example, I just have one parameter `a`  to determine. However, I probably have several parameters to determine in my real problem.

Comment: @Zihu Guo ParametricNDSolve can work with many Parameters. With the plots you can easily ascertain, if the conditions are complied.

Comment: thank you very much, I will try this on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to the Answer by Willinski, only limited ranges of `a` are consistent with the boundary conditions in the Question.  So, for instance,

```
Plot[x[a][10] /. s, {a, -3, 1}]
```

generates

[image]

along with a number of error messages.  Consistent with this figure,  Willinsi's plots show that `a == -1` and `a == 0` satisfy the boundary condition `x[10] == 8`, but `a == 1` does not.  Warning: Some details of my figure may be incorrect, because `Plot` samples the function only at a discrete number of points.

Within the wide range for which the figure above shows `x[10] == 8` to be satisfied, it is straightforward to obtain `y[0]`, for instance, as a function of `a`.

```
ParametricPlot[{a, y[a][0] /. s}, {a, -2.9, -0.6}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "y[0]"}]
```

[image]

One might hope that `a` could be computed for a particular value of `y[0]` using the method described in [Boundary Value Problems with Parameters](http://Boundary%20Value%20Problems%20with%20Parameters).

```
ss = NDSolve[{x''[t] == y[t] x[t], y'[t] == 2 - a[t] x[t], a'[t] == 0,
    x[0] == 0, x[10] == 8, y[0] == -24, y[10] == 3.5}, {x, y, a}, t]
```

Unfortunately, this procedure does not work here, generating error message and an answer that does not satisfy the boundary conditions.